# CSS Div : Align Everything inisde if div to bottom

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

i am trying to bulid this graph... heres the problem

[TAKE A LOOK AT THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/uYghh/).. i want these divs "#green" to be aligned to the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How is this?](http://jsfiddle.net/uYghh/1/)

[image: display: inline-block]

I changed your `float: left` to `display: inline-block` which by default has a `vertical-align: baseline` I believe.

[Check out how to do one for IE6 and IE7.](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/)

Also, as a sidenote, you should assign **one `id` attribute to one element**. Use a class otherwise.

Comment: that's partially right but you see they are not aligned to the bottom-line of the container div

Answer (score 2):

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/uYghh/16/

change the `left` value to move them around.

edit: updated sample for correct margins.

Comment: not a good idea... this will be container relative & the settings here will be according to some pages theme & all.. can't plug them into other sites... re-usability is an issue

Comment: if you don't add `left` or `top` values to `position: relative`, it behaves as a default element on the flow of the document. I use this all the time and it is in fact reusable.  alex's answer is, in fact more elegant though.

Answer (score 1):

please change the id property of the green divs to some thing different to each other
  http://jsfiddle.net/uYghh/33/

Comment: here you go but if you want some automation use java script to move the bars from the left on some percent http://jsfiddle.net/uYghh/33/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left;` use `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

Change your css by this

```
#green
{
    position: relative;
    float : left;
    width  : 20px;
    top:100%;
    margin : 5px;
    border: solid 1px #0fb551;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#0fb551), to(#064d23));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0fb551, #064d23);
    background: linear-gradient(#0fb551, #064d23);   
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#0fb551, #064d23);
    behavior: url(pie.htc);    
}

Add some jQuery to your project

$(function(){
    $('#graph div').each(function(){
        var ht=$(this).height();
        $(this).css({'margin-top':-ht-4+'px'});

    });
});
```